# How can I get these files to work on GitHub Pages?

Tags: directory

The issue I have is my page isn't working, and I get the 404 File Not Found every time I try to load up that page. This happened once I put my index.html and styles.css file into a folder. [This is the link](https://github.com/Proudity/W-W-L-S-F) What's wrong with the page, and how can I fix it?

I tried to take them both out of the file, and it worked. But keeping them both just out of the files would make it kind of unorganized, so I tried putting them back in folders, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GitHub Pages websites follows the same structure as your directory seen on the repository. So for your current structure, with the files inside '*/test*' the link becomes: https://proudity.github.io/W-W-L-S-F/test/index.html

If the files are on the highest level of you directory (**outside any folder**), the link would be:
https://proudity.github.io/W-W-L-S-F/index.html

You can refer to the [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site#next-steps).
Let me know if you have any more questions !